# Set button color with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a HTML button, I want it to blink when the user clicks it. during blink its color should turn to green and when its blink finished, I want it to turn to default color, I use below javascript code to force it blink and change its color but the problem is that I can not set the default color. if I use `document.getElementById("reset").style.backgroundColor = '';` after these codes,  the button color does not changed, how to set the default color with javascript?

```
$("#reset").fadeTo(200, 0.1).fadeTo(400, 1.0);
document.getElementById("reset").style.backgroundColor = '#00FF00';
```

Comment: Try `background` instead of `backgroundColor`

Comment: We need the other part of the code - `HTML`, `CSS` .

Comment: perhaps `$("#reset").css({"background-color": "#00FF00"});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the button to *blink* on click- in pure CSS

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Psy8t/1/)

HTML

```
<button>Click Me</button>
```

CSS

```
button {
    background:grey;
}
button:focus {
    -webkit-animation-name:blink;
    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 3;
    animation-name:blink;
    animation-duration:1s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: 3;
}
@keyframes blink {
    0% {
        background:grey;
    }
    50% {
        background:green;
    }
    100% {
        background:grey;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
    0% {
        background:grey;
    }
    50% {
        background:green;
    }
    100% {
        background:grey;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use javascript for this, if you want to change the background of a button on click, just use the :active css selector

```
<button class="button">This is a button</button>
```

And the following css

```
.button {
    background-color: #00FF00;
}

.button:active {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s4LRT/

This way, you can also add css transitions easily

Answer (score 0):

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/K5aqu/)

**HTML**

```
<div id='reset'>
  BGColor Here
</div>

<input type='button' value='Reset' id='resetButton1' >
<input type='button' value='Reset' id='resetButton2' >
```

**JS**

```
$('#resetButton2').css({"display":"none"});

$('#resetButton1').click(function(){
  $("#reset").css({"background-color": "#00FF00"});   
  $('#resetButton1').css({"display":"none"});
  $('#resetButton2').css({"display":"inline"});
});

$('#resetButton2').click(function(){
  $("#reset").css({"background-color": ""});   
  $('#resetButton2').css({"display":"none"});
  $('#resetButton1').css({"display":"inline"});
});
```

Comment: the problem is how to retrieve default color after click, with this code the green color remains even after blink

Comment: @user3511155 i have updated my answer, review it... :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already have jQuery loaded, so you might want to consider using the jQuery methods for adjusting this.

```
$('#reset').css('background-color', '#00ff00');
```

Additionally, you can leverage the `toggleClass`, `addClass`, and `removeClass` methods to move the styling into your stylesheets.

```
$('#reset').addClass('testing');
```

But in my own testing, the code you have above works just fine.